# Safe way to purge history - Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I cloned a project to my local directory and made a lot of changes. My current goal is to push my changed code to a new branch in the remote repository. And eventually this new branch will be merged back to default.

My problem is, because of some stupid effort in the past a few weeks to try to recover some missing files, I end up with a few branch names that I don't want being shown in public.

Here's what I have:

```
$hg branches  
dev-v02  197:xxxxx  
dev2     194:xxxxx  
dev      183:xxxxx  
qa       189:xxxxx

$hg branch  
dev-v02
```

My question is, if I push my current branch dev-v02 to the remote repository by "hg push --new-branch", and this branch later get merged back to default, will the unwanted branches show up in history of default? And if so, is there a safe way to purge them? 
I do NOT want to discard my changes. I just don't want the unwanted branches showing up in "hg branches" or "hg his" commands by whoever later clones the project from the remote repository. I searched online and found "hg strip" but I couldn't tell from the article if it would also remove the changes I've made. Thanks.

Edit: I just cloned my local repository by "hg clone -r 197 original-dir dest-dir" as suggested by both kevin and chessbot and now hg branches shows:
dev-02 192:xxxxx
qa     187:xxxxx (inactive)
I guess "qa" remains because I had pushed it to the remote as a QA branch and closed it later, and I just have to live with that. I will push from this new directory from now on. Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `hg push --new-branch -b dev-v02` to specify that you're pushing only that branch.

(See: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/push)

Another thing you could do: Clone the repository locally on your machine, strip out the branches you don't want, and then push that clone to the server. Then you retain your history locally without pushing it to everyone else.

Comment: Just edited my questions to make it clearer in that what I really care about is that people who cloned my project from the repository later will not see those unwanted branches in their "hg his" command. If "hg push --new-branch -b dev-v02" could do the trick, I have found my solution. Can you confirm that? Sorry, but at this point I am afraid of "trying" anything.

Comment: Just confirmed with a test project that this works. If you'd like I can post my testing code.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried selectively cloning my repository locally as suggested and it works.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

Branches are permanently associated with a commit.  The branch is part of the commit, and contributes to the hash.  Changing the branch of a commit in the past would alter all commit hashes from that point forward.  This is quite different from Git, where a branch is little more than an ephemeral pointer to a HEAD.  Such pointers are implemented in Mercurial as bookmarks.

If the unwanted branches appear on commits which are (ancestors of) commits you want to publish, there is very little you can do, short of recreating the history with all-new hashes.  This could (for instance) be done with `hg export` and `hg import`, along with local cloning and (probably) a certain amount of shell scripting.  More efficiently, you could use [the convert extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--branchmap) to automate the process.  Since this changes commit hashes, it will likely cause serious problems if any of the commits have already been distributed publicly.

If you have no interest in sharing the offending commits, you can simply not publish them.  This can be done with selective pushing.  However, since you'll always have to manually exclude those commits every time you push, it's probably safer to clone and strip (or clone selectively with the `-r` flag).  You can then push from your partial clone with impunity.  Assuming you have a sufficiently recent version of Mercurial, you can also force the commits into the secret [phase](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases), so that they will not be pushed:

```
hg phase -fs revisions
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `hg strip`, because it permanently removes the commits from the history *(see [Editing History](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EditingHistory) in the Mercurial wiki)*

If I were you, I would close the branches instead:

```
hg up -C badbranch
hg commit --close-branch -m 'close badbranch, this approach never worked'
hg up -C default
```

*(source: [Pruning branches](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PruningDeadBranches) in the Mercurial wiki)*

After closing a branch, `hg branches` doesn't show it anymore.

If you *do* want to see closed branches, use the `-c` parameter:

```
hg branches -c
```

---

**Disadvantage:**

`hg his` still shows closed branches.

You could use the `-b` parameter though, to show only the default branch:

```
hg his -b default
```